# How to insert mutiple select statements into table uisng SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

For example I have got 2 tables Employee and Department.
With the queries like

```
Select EmpID,Employee From dbo.Employee

Select DepID,DeptName From dbo.Department
```

which I have put 2 EXECUTE SQL tasks.

and want to insert those select statements into some Destination table.
Output :

```
ID  SQL_Stmt
1  Select EmpID,Employee From dbo.Employee
2  Select DepID,DeptName From dbo.Department
```

where as my structure looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to store the text of the query or the results of the query?

Comment: @billinkc I'm trying to store text of the query

Comment: You could make the queries themelves variables, and if you need to execute them execute as variable, and then you can take the variables and save them into the table as text from the variable.  Though I am not seeing why you would want/need to do this?

Comment: Don't copy data from table to table, data should only be stored once. Create a view instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda tough to say what you're doing here, but judging by the SELECT statements and the destination table layout it seems to me that it would be simpler to merge the two SELECT statements into one SELECT statement that joins on an ID column which appears to be in the destination table, so I'll assume ID is in the source tables too.

**IMPORTANT:** If there isn't a relationship (such as ID) between [dbo].[Employee] and [dbo].[Department] then they **SHOULD NOT** be inserted into the same destination table. Your table will not be normalized, which is bad.

Ideally, your source query would be similar to

```
SELECT  Emp.EmpID
       ,Emp.Employee
       ,Dept.DeptName
       ,Dept.Department
FROM [dbo].[Employee] Emp 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Department] Dept
ON Emp.ID=Dept.ID
```

Here ends the SQL and begins the SSIS:
You'll need to create a Data Flow task in SSIS.
Within the Data Flow task you'll need an OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination tasks.
Open the OLE DB Source task and select the "Data Access Mode" dropdown menu and change it to the "SQL Command" option.
Now you can write your SQL Query as the source you'll be inserting into your destination table.

[image: SQL Query]

Connect the OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination and select the destination table from the "Name of the table or view:" dropdown menu.
Columns with the same name should be automatically mapped together, but you may need to manually map columns which are not alike.

You should be able to resolve any other errors that arise on your own. Good luck!

TL;DR: You're trying to achieve something on the Control Flow level of SSIS which should actually be done on the Data Flow level.